# Using NodeGit CloneOptions to clone a branch

Tags: node.js, git, libgit2

I am trying to work out how to pass clone options to the nodegit clone method.

The node git documentation states that the 3rd param to the clone method is the clone options object
http://www.nodegit.org/nodegit/#Repo-clone

```
git.Repo.clone(URL, path, CloneOptions, callback);
```

However this object is not included in the standard build of nodegit.

I have added the binding for the clone_options.cc file into the bindings.gyp file and I can get access to the clone options object. However I can not work out how to instantiate it with a valid branch name. 
The libgit2 api shows that the option is checkout_branch
http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_clone_options

Anyone have any insight on how to do this? Or on an alternative library that supports cloning of git branches in node?

```
var CloneOptions = nodegit.CloneOptions;
var options = new CloneOptions({checkout_branch: branchName});
git.Repo.clone(url, temp, options, function (err, repo) {...});
```

results in

```
Error: git_clone_options is required.
```

There is also an open thread on the github issues page for nodegit

https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/127

Comment: You can also try change property on your code: `checkout_branch` to `checkoutBranch`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this...

```
    var Git = require('nodegit');
    var clone = Git.Clone.clone;
    var branch = 'development';
    var cloneOptions = new Git.CloneOptions();    

    cloneOptions.checkoutBranch = branch;  
    clone(url, directory, cloneOptions)
        .then(function(repository){
            console.log(repository);
        });
```

Comment: getting error new Git.cloneOptions(); is not a constructor @Leandro William

Comment: cant we do using simple-git package?